# Cannot run Exec with DAO Grid on other machine

Tags: ms-access, vb6, dao

I have a problem with a old program running a DAO Grid. (yeah I know, not my choice)
 In a new project I have recreated the issue and it looks like the Records-set won't 'bind' to the Data1-object.

I have tested it on 32/64bits, Win7/8.1/10 machines. 
 On the development machine it works fine. (in VB6 and as an Exec-program)

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
 Dim tmpDB As Database
 Dim r As Recordset
 On Error Resume Next

 Set tmpDB = OpenDatabase("test.mdb", 0, False)
 Set r = tmpDB.OpenRecordset("Budget")
 Set Data1.Recordset = r

 Text1.Text = r.RecordCount 'works fine
 Text2.Text = Data1.Recordset.RecordCount 
 If (Err.Number <> 0) Then Text2.Text = Err.Description
 'Object variable or With block variable not set; on other machines
 End Sub
```

I have checked component versions, registration, file access...It all seems fine.

Below are two screen captures. Left is the not working version, Right is on the dev. machine running.
 It opens a database, getting a recordset and counts the records twice. First from the Recordset-object, second time from the Data1-object. The last one don't work on other machines

What I do notice is that the exec on the client machine is not creating a ldb-file. But the data can be accessed in the Recordset
[image]

Comment: Try specifying the options, (RecordsetOptionEnum), so you are sure you don't have a forward only cursor that can't be bound to the data1 control. Also, comment out the `On Error Resume Next` so you can see errors while debugging, or write a proper error handler.

Comment: Hi Jac, Good tip. I have set the RecordsetOption. I can jump around in the "r"  object (back and forward). So no forward only cursor. The on error resume next was just for the test and catching the error description on a nice-ish way. The problem is in the line Data1.Recordset=r After that point the Data1.Recordset is still null. (before and after the options set)

Comment: It's not simply some sort of delay in loading the grid? Does `Data1.Recordset Is Nothing` return `True` either straight after you've `Set` it or after the `RecordCount` failure (assuming you leave `On Error Resume Next` on?

Comment: Hi Mark, no it is not a delay. the Data1.Recordset is just don't set. (without error) The tip from Jac was interesting, because I didn't see a ldb-file. After changing the options, I have now exclusive rights, which has as result no ldp-file in all situation. (but program does work on dev.machine within VB6 and as exec. but not on other machines.)

Answer (score -1):

use Data1.Refresh

to get RecordCount you may need to do MoveLast then MoveFirst;